# Use fields between OneToOneField in a model

Tags: django, django-models

I am in a situation where I cannot use inheritance. Say I have two models, a `Person` and a `Passport`, for this example assume they have a One-to-one relationship:

```
class Passport(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField()



class Person(models.Model):
    passport = models.OneToOneField(Passport)
```

Now from here, I want to get a `Person`'s `full_name`. In my application, a `Person` cannot exist  without a unique `Passport`, so how do I access the `full_name` attribute through a `Person` object. I ultimately want to be able to do something like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    passport = models.OneToOneField(Passport)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.passport.full_name
```

Is there a simple solution to this is Django?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Yeah your example works 100%.

Comment: This is my mistake - turns out one of my models was added without syncing/migrating my database. I was receiving and error that made me think this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the simple and correct way of doing this is exactly what you did: self.passport.full_name returns the full name of the person, which is an attribute of the passport.

Notice that because the passport ForeignKey cannot be null as you defined it, the self.passport will always exist.